# Matching string values between two workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I want to Inspect matching string values of multiple cells in workbook to row in another workbook. I wrote this code, but it does not achieve this task.

The row, first problem FS, r1 var assigned empty when running code and the matching statement it does not achieve the goal. I need help if there any method to achieve that.

```
Sub checkcustomerID()


On Error Resume Next

Dim y As Workbook
Dim x As Workbook

Set y = ActiveWorkbook
Set x = Workbooks.Open("\\Eng_badia-pc\e\WALEED SOBEH ENGINEERING OFFICE\W-01-ADMINSTRATIVE DEPARTMENT\W-01-AD-1-SALES\W-01-D1-S1-STATMENTS\03-PROJECTS TRACKER.xlsm")

'--------------------------------------  'Inspect matching of values of multiple cells in _
                                          workbook1 to row in another workbook


For i = 1 To y.Sheets.Count
For j = 1 To x.Sheets.Count
FS1 = y.Sheets(i).Range("b3").Value
FS2 = y.Sheets(i).Range("b6").Value
FS3 = y.Sheets(i).Range("e6").Value
FS4 = y.Sheets(i).Range("h6").Value
FS5 = y.Sheets(i).Range("b7").Value
FS6 = y.Sheets(i).Range("h7").Value
FS7 = y.Sheets(i).Range("e7").Value

R1 = x.Sheets(j).Range("d:d").Value
R2 = x.Sheets(j).Range("m:m").Value
R3 = x.Sheets(j).Range("n:n").Value
R4 = x.Sheets(j).Range("o:o").Value
R5 = x.Sheets(j).Range("p:p").Value
R6 = x.Sheets(j).Range("q:q").Value
R7 = x.Sheets(j).Range("r:r").Value

If FS1 = R1 And FS2 = R2 And FS3 = R3 And _
FS4 = R4 And FS5 = R6 And FS6 = R6 And FS6 = R6 Then

MsgBox "The Customer " & "" & x.Sheets(j).Range("d" & j) & "and have Customer ID:" & x.Sheets(j).Range("b" & j)

Sheets(i).Names = x.Sheets(j).Range("b" & j + 3)

Else:

MsgBox "New Customer "

End If

Next j

Next i

End Sub
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Ensure your `Sheets(n)` reference in both loops is pointing to the desired target worksheet.

Comment: You are comparing single values with ranges, that is doomed to fail.

Comment: I would use the find method here